# IValueConverter Using Lookup Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, ivalueconverter

I am using a converter like this:

```
    public class BreedConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        static ObservableCollection<Breed_> Breeds = Breed_.GetBreeds();

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && Breeds.Count > 0)
            {
                short breedID = (short)value;
                Breed_ breed = Breeds.Single(s => s.BreedID == breedID);
                return (string)breed.Breed;
            }
            else
                return "";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

The Breeds collection is retrieved from a SQL Server database.  I want to retrieve it once and then use it to do the conversion.  I don't want to go to the database each and every time I need to convert.

Is there a better way to do this, e.g. ResourceDictionary (which I don't know how to use in this scenario, since I'm still a noob)?

Comment: I don't think you really need an IValueConverter in this instance. In your main class/window I'd recommend creating your observable collection there, and only one time. Then you could use INotifyPropertyChange to convert, pass back the breed you are wanting.

Comment: I’m not sure how to do that. I’m a noob. There will be a bunch of breed IDs in a TreeView. I just want to convert the breed ID to the name of the breed.

Comment: Move your collection to DataContext class e.g. `ViewModel`. Then use MultiBinding and `IMultiValueConverter` pass both there: ID and Collection.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been able to get to work.  As @Darthchai mentioned, I have created the collection in the class/window.  However, I cannot figure out how to use INotifyPropertyChanged to let the specific TextBlock know to do the conversion.  I am a noob, after all.  :)  What I was able to do - and I don't know if this is the right approach - was to use the Loaded event of the TextBlock to do the conversion.  here is the code:

```
        private void BreedTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
            if (textBlock != null && Breeds.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    short breedID = short.Parse(textBlock.Text);
                    Breed_ breed = Breeds.Single(s => s.BreedID == breedID);
                    textBlock.Text = (string)breed.Breed;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            return;
        }
```